# What does it mean when the names of images in your "drawable" folder are red?

Tags: android, android-studio

Sometimes when I put images in my "drawable" folder, the image name is red. Doing right-click->Synchronize doesn't seem to help at all, and they crash my app when I try to use them in an activity. What does it mean and what should I do to fix this?

EDIT: It says "out of memory error." I think the image is too big, actually, not to do with teh red thing.

Comment: Images name must be in lowercase and no special symbols, you can just use underscore `_`

Comment: How do they  crash your app?

Comment: I use the red-named image and as soon as I get to that activity, the app crashes. Then I switch it to a white-named image and no more crashing. All lower-case name with no special characters.

Comment: @user3169700 Please edit the post by providing the exception from logcat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means those files are untracked by git. You may want to add them to your git repo (this will make them green)

But.. they won't crash your application.. there's something else going on then

Answer (score 3):

Means your project is connected to `git` and you can push edits to make it green, or just ignore that!

> and they crash my app when I try to use them in an activity.

May that happen because you name images in uppercase or their name contains special characters, it's must be in lowercase and no symbols.

**EDIT:**

It's crashes because it's a big images, just use small images because you deal with piece of limited resources, and it will be great if it a `PNG`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes When the file name starts with a Capital letter a red underline is shown.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).